# SASS rem to px convertion without over-writing existing style sheets

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, sass, web-frontend

I'm new to SASS. I'm working on a project using SASS. I have completed the project and it is working perfectly in most of the browsers except IE8. I noticed rem values are not supported in ie8.

Now I need solution for this without touching the existing SASS files. Is there any possibility of having a mixin file which converts rem to px values?

Comment: Sass doesn't work that way.

Comment: can you help with any other possible way?

Comment: What you're asking for requires a 3rd party tool, and those kinds of requests are off-topic here.

Comment: I need something like "autoprefixer" which converts px value fallback :(

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following plugin to convert the rem values to px values. It is much easy to use and works perfectly.

[npm plugin for rem to px value](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixrem)